# If $E(Y\mid X) = E(Y)$, do we have $X,Y$ independent?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, independence

We know that if $X,Y$ are independent, then $E(Y\mid X) = E(Y)$. But what about the converse?

Comment: Any thoughts?  As an observation...knowing about the expectation of a distribution really tells you very little about the distribution itself.  For example, the standard normal and the constant $0$ both have expectation $0$.

Comment: Do you mean $ (\mathbb E \mathbb E(Y|X)) = \mathbb E(Y) $?

Answer (score 2):

No. Here is the joint distribution of a counterexample:
\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
&&&X&\\
&&-1&0&1\\\hline
&1& 1/6& 0&1/6 &\\
Y&0& 0& 1/3& 0&\\
  &-1 & 1/6&0 &1/6
\end{array}
Note $E(Y|X=x)=0$ for all $x\in \{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this specific example, E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)=0, X and Y are independent.

Comment: @YaoZhao You should double-check the definition of independence. If $X$ and $Y$ were independent, you would have $P(X=0\cap Y=0)=P(X=0)\cdot P(Y=0)$, but here, $1/3\neq 1/3\cdot 1/3.$ When $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$, you say $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: I see. You are right! Thank you so much!